# why there is syntax error in cmd while using pandas? what's wrong with this code-

Tags: pandas, ipython, python-3.6

I don't understand why this error occurred.

Code is:

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: df=pandas.Dataframe<[[2,4,6],[7,8,9]]>
  File "<ipython-input-2-f02f395d63af>", line 1
      df=pandas.Dataframe<[[2,4,6],[7,8,9]]>
```

Error is as follows:

```
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And then it happened again:

```
In [3]: df1=pandas.DataFrame<[[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]>
  File "<ipython-input-3-02c337851cc9>", line 1
      df1=pandas.DataFrame<[[2,3,4],[5,6,7]]>
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: are they <> or ()?

Comment: Yes they are <>

Comment: change them to ()

Comment: Thanks, it helped:

Answer (score 1):

`df=pandas.Dataframe<[[2,4,6],[7,8,9]]>` is indeed invalid Python syntax. The literals `<` and `>` are comparators. You will want to replace those with `(` and `)`.

Your second problem is that `Dataframe` is not an attribute of `pandas`. `DataFrame` (capital F) however, is.

So, you want:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame([[2,4,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: DataFrame, not Dataframe

Comment: Haha, yes, of course. I even mentioned that myself. :-) Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It's because you were using<> instead of ()

> df=pandas.Dataframe([[2,4,6],[7,8,9]])

Use This^